# _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError Freezing wxPython Program

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

My app is written in Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8, and accesses a MySQL database. I have had issues with the program freezing when doing an add via:-

```
cursor.execute(sql ([idSession, TestDateTime, DataBLOb]))
```

Although this is in *try: - except:* construct it never executes the except portion. I have run this section from the command line and got:-

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

Obviously I need to investigate the cause of the error but how can I get my software to execute the *except:* code rather than just freeze!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to create a new Thread. Look the code:

```
from threading import Thread

class Spam(wx.Frame):

    def doStuff(self, arg1,arg2,arg3)
        # Do Something...
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql ([idSession, TestDateTime, DataBLOb]))
        except Exception a e:
            # Do the treatments or show a dialog

    def ButtonClick(self, event): # Assuming a button like "do this operation"
        t = Thread(target=self.doStuff,args=(arg1,arg2,arg3))
        t.start()
```

#### Observation:

The function doStuff need to be free of errors, if some error raised and not is  treated will create a deadlock, or a zombie thread.